# Why is gdb not finding any debugging symbols, even though I have -g at every stage of compilation and linkage in my Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gdb

I downloaded gdb 9.1 on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.2. I am trying to debug an executable from a code written in C called test that is created in my Makefile and linked to a static library. I have tried putting -g and -ggdb at all compilation lines and linkage lines. I make sure to use `make clean` every time I make changes then run `make test` to rerun the Makefile. My Makefile reads as the following:

```
all: main
    mkdir -p build/bin
    mkdir -p build/lib
    mkdir -p build/objects
    mv *.o build/objects
    mv *.a build/lib
    mv main build/bin

main: main.o liblinkedlist.a
    gcc main.o -g -o main -llinkedlist -L.

test: test.o liblinkedlist.a
    gcc test.o -g -o test -llinkedlist -L.
    mkdir -p build/bin
    mkdir -p build/lib
    mkdir -p build/objects
    mv *.o build/objects
    mv *.a build/lib

test.o: src/bin/test.c
    gcc src/bin/test.c -g -c -I include

main.o: src/bin/main.c
    gcc -g src/bin/main.c -c -I include

liblinkedlist.a: src/lib.c
    gcc src/lib.c -g -c -I include
    ar rs liblinkedlist.a lib.o

clean:
    rm -rf build
    rm -f test
    rm -f main
```

When I try to do `gdb ./test` it gives me the following lines of code in the terminal:

Reading symbols from ./test...

warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/Users/eamonohare/Desktop/Spring_2020_Classes/CSE_109/homework-3/./liblinkedlist.a"

warning: `/Users/eamonohare/Desktop/Spring_2020_Classes/CSE_109/homework-3/test.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
(No debugging symbols found in ./test)

(gdb)

I have tried the solution to every other user having this problem and none of them worked. I am not sure how I can solve this.

Comment: `mv *.a build/lib` Could be because you moved away all the objects and libraries to a different path after linking.

Comment: That solved the no debug signal error, but now I am getting an error when I try to run the code. (gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/eamonohare/Desktop/Spring_2020_Classes/CSE_109/homework-3/test 
[New Thread 0x1a03 of process 72391]
[New Thread 0x2703 of process 72391] Then it just sits at this line and does nothing.

Comment: Does it do anything if you run the program directly without gdb?

Comment: Yeah the program tries to run but gets a 29 segmentation fault

Comment: Sorry, can't really help you further without a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Could be that you have bugs which result in undefined behaviour. Since it is UB it may do one thing when run with gdb and something else when run directly. In gdb you could try ctrl-c to see if that will break into your program and if so you can get stack trace and debug further.

Comment: ctrl-c does not exit for some reason

Comment: ctrl-z worked to stop gdb. Where can I find the stack trace? This was the only line it printed after I stopped it: [1]+  Stopped                 gdb ./test

Comment: ctrl-z suspends gdb itself and is not what you want. ctrl-c normally stops the program being debugged and drops back into the gdb prompt. As I said, I can't help you much more without an MVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the source code, the object file, and the executable file in the same directory as where you are running `gdb`

There are other ways, which require some simple commands into `gdb` before entering `run`, however; they are a nuisance to redo over and over.